# Connect two MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website that is using SMF forum (simplemachines.org). I have been using it also as the site's login by leveraging the SSI.php file which is basically an API for the forum.

Now that I am this far in my site project, I want to add additional functionality. One thing I want to do is add lots of custom variables that a user can have, which is difficult when modifying the built-in users table of SMF. I also want to allow users to join "teams". A team can have multiple users in it.

I have been playing around with PHP and MySQL and have learned how to create a user registration script and add a user to a simple **single** database table (no longer using SMF).

The database table has:

> ID, Username, Password (not plaintext), Date

How do I take my SQL knowledge to the next level; I want to now create a table called Teams which will logically hold this data: An ID, a Name, Admin True/False (I want multiple team members to be admins if needed).

I figure a form should be created that will make a new Team. When submitted, if the team name doesn't already exist, create a new team, and the user that MADE the team should automatically be the first admin.

1) I have no idea how to link 2 tables, which is the entire point of this topic. When I create a user profile page, I want it to list the teams he is in.

This means it needs to take his user ID from the Users table and **connect** it to the Teams table and if it finds his ID in that Teams table, return the array containing all of his teams he is in and I'll display them how I want.

> I think that I posted way too much detail but it will help you help
>   me. Additionally, that above knowledge will help me with everything
>   else I want to do, like adding multiple teams to some other table.
>   It's all the same once you know how to do it!!
>
> Thanks!

2) Just realized another problem of mine, once I have this custom database, I lose the ability to provide single sign-on on the forum, which is awesome. Two accounts to interact on website and interact on forum is really stupid. Does phpBB or other "Big Player" Forum have a way to easily use custom database logins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of 'linking' the two tables would be to create a membership table such as

```
MembershipTable
-----------------------------
| UserID | TeamID | IsAdmin |
-----------------------------
```

This way, the user's details is kept in the Users table and team definition information stays in the teams table.

If for a user with an userid $id, you want to find all the teams it is a member of, you can run a simple SQL query:

```
SELECT t.team_name
FROM   MembershipTable m
LEFT JOIN team_table t on M.userID = t.UserID
```

Should be simple to infer from the above what the definitions of the `user` and `team` tables should look like.

Comment: Wow that is genius. Is that common practice? It completely eliminates redundant data which the solution in my head would have had. I have no idea what the t. and M. do though. Know of a good site that I can brush up on my sql at?

Comment: The `t` and `m` is just a shorthand to distinguish between the two tables. I'd say it's common practice to move the associations to a separate table - it keeps the data normalized (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). See http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~spector/sql.pdf for a really good intro to SQL.

Comment: @pr0tocol: Very good observation. That's one of the main advantages of normalization: minimum redundancy.

Comment: You may also consider this variation: Instead of using a boolean field (IsAdmin) which gives you two choices, you can use a `CHAR(1)` field (say called `Role`) that stores `'A'` for Admins and `'U'` for Users. This way you can later add more roles (`'B'` for B-admins, `'Z'` for Zombies, etc.) if you need to, without altering the database structure.